# Where can I get windows 10 upgrade advisor for volume license?

Tags: upgrade, windows-10, migration-assistant, volume-license

I have the **volume licensed Windows 8** (not 8.1) installed. I would like to know whether it would be OK for me to upgrade to **Windows 10**. The "free" upgrade is only available to non-volume licensed Windows. **I don't care about free**, but I would like that advisor that comes with it.

Surely as I actually paid for Windows 10 I would have this options available?

Or do only people with free upgrade available to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), You have to go to the [Volume Licencing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx) for more information on how to optain Windows 10.

Comment: I already have Windows 10 downloaded. But I want to run a compatibility check first. I don't want to destroy my computer (my environment) by running it blindly.

Comment: @SmartK8 Then don’t install it. Simple as that. If your computer is mission-critical(-ish), you can always try it on another machine.

Comment: I already checked it on virtual machine, but what's the point? I need to know whether my installation will be OK. Why people who have free upgrade have a chance to check compatibility and I don't? A punishment for paying for a MSDN subscription? I still can't believe this is the case. It's too ridiculous to be true.